# Aliasing struct members

Tags: c, struct, c-preprocessor, alias

I have a struct that might have 2 or 4 members depending on a preprocessor definition.

```
struct foo {
    int m1;
    int m2;
    #ifdef MORE_MEMBERS
    int m3;
    int m4;
    #endif
}
```

I have functions that take `foo.m3` and `foo.m4` as arguments. Because of that, I get a compilation error when `MORE_MEMBERS` isn't defined.

I'm trying to avoid adding `#ifdef` at every function call. Is there some way to make `m3` and `m4` be aliases/dummies when `MORE_MEMBERS` isn't defined? I'd like to still keep the struct size equal to `sizeof(int) * 2`.

Comment: Yes redesign your code. You are using a terrible pattern. A function should perhaps take `strcut foo` parameter instead, but it's impossible to help you further because there is not enough information. The only thing that is pretty clear is, that you have a severe design problem.

Comment: It's not my code. I'm trying to add a feature to someone else's code by making as few changes as possible. The previous code already has functions that take foo.m1 instead of foo.

Comment: What are the functions that take `foo.m3` and/or `foo.m4` going to do if `MORE_MEMBERS` isn't defined?

Comment: @cschneid they will ignore them. So it doesn't matter what value they take, just that they don't throw compilation errors and don't take space in the struct.

Comment: If the functions don't use their parameters, why are the parameters defined?  You need to rethink.  You're heading towards disaster!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Iharob, it's horrible code. It's not too clear what you're after, but it sounds like you could use a `union`:

```
struct foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

union bar
{
    struct foo m1m2;
    struct foo m3m4;
};

void f(union bar *x)
{
    printf("%d", x->m1m2.a);
    printf("%d", x->m3m4.b);
}
```

Comment: Something like this seems like it could work. But I don't want to change the calling functions. Can I make unions of {m1,m3} and {m2,m4} as data members, while still keeping them accessible as foo.m1, foo.m3 etc?

Comment: Why don't you want to change the calling functions? - it feels like you probably should. Unions can be members of a structure, yes.

Comment: These functions are used in a lot of different places through the code, places that have no relation to what I'm changing. If I change the function declaration, I'd have to change the function calls there too.
I guess I'll ask on softwareengineering if I should make wrapper functions or use unions.

Comment: @devil0150: do you require C89 compatibility? (If so you could use the super ugly `#define m3 m1` if the name `m3` is not used elsewhere. But don't tell anyone I suggested that :) )

Comment: @rici Are you saying that wouldn't work with later C standards?

Comment: @devil0150: no, with modern C you can use anonymous unions, which is less filthy.